# How do I check if the ProcessPoolExecutor is full?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We want to know if the executor has reached max_workers. Is there a simple way to find out how many workers are running in the following code?

```py
import concurrent.futures


def dummy_process(arg_a, arg_b):
    print("ml_process", arg_a, arg_b)
    time.sleep(5)

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

def main():
    while True:
        executor.submit(dummy_process, "test_a", "test_b")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

use try except

```
import concurrent.futures


def dummy_process(arg_a, arg_b):
    print("ml_process", arg_a, arg_b)
    time.sleep(5)

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

def main():
    while True:
        try:
           executor.submit(dummy_process, "test_a", "test_b")
        except:
           print("Pool Executer is Full")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: never ever do a catch-all `except:` _and_ entirely disregard the specific exception that was caught

Comment: i know it was just a simple example to show him the idea cause i am not sure how he want to handle the exception

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In our case, if the worker is full, we just want to output the log, if not, we want to submit(). This is fine if it is caught correctly, however is this not caught, right? We want something like isFull().